# Странное поведение при обращении по ссылке на элемент через ref во Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Есть модальное окно, которое отображается/скрывается по `v-if`.
Внутри окна есть элемент (к примеру input) у которого указано свойство `ref="myInput"`. В

```js
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$refs.myInput)
}
```

при первом открытии модального окна показывает DOM-элемент, все ок, НО, после того как модальное окно закрыть и заново открыть уже в консоли отображает:

```
null
<input>...
```

если опять закрыть и опять открыть, то:

```
null
null
<input>...
```

и т.д.
Я выяснил, что это из-за `v-if`, если заменить на `v-show`, то все ок, но мне необходим `v-if`, т.к. `v-show` не удаляет элемент из DOM-дерева, а только ставит ему `display: none;`, это плохо для меня тем, что в инпуте сохраняется все что там ввели, а после закрытия модального окна (без сохранения данных) и открытии вновь инпут не обновится оп дефолту.
Есть ли способ как справится с данной проблемой?

**UPD**: данное поведение было из-за использования библиотеки `mitt` при вызове события в котором шло обращение к элементу по `ref`, и чтобы избежать данного поведения необходимо было перед инициализацией события прописать `this.emitter.all.clear()`, т.е.:

```
await this.emitter.all.clear()
await this.emitter.on('onNewEvent', () => { ... })
```

Comment: Все же логично: есть элемент - возвращается элемент; нет элемента - возвращается `null`. Что именно тут подразумевается под "проблемой"?

Comment: @yar85 проблема в том, что когда пытаешься получить `this.$refs.myInput.value` получаешь ошибку. И это поведение не логично. После отрисовки элемент есть, но возвращает `null`

Comment: В том и дело, что я ошибок не получаю - именно поэтому и уточняю суть проблемы вопроса. Вероятно, твой код не учитывает что `$refs` без реактивности (т.е. накосячено может быть на уровне логики действий алгоритма, а не на уровне выражений в коде) - но пока в вопросе нет внятного словесного объяснения и/или не добавлен [repro], невозможно что-то определенно сказать...

Comment: @yar85 согласен, не явно описал проблему, попробую воспроизвести ситуацию в песочнице и обновлю попозже

Comment: @yar85 да, дело было не в странном поведении vue, дело в моей организации кода, моя невнимательность. Спасибо что направили в нужном направлении

Comment: Вопрос все же надо уточнить - и чтобы дать участникам "на что отвечать", и чтобы тебе репутацию не снизили возможными минусами. Тем более ответы все же могут быть полезны, если ошибка была допущена из-за проблем оф.документации (доки у Vue хорошие в оригинале, а вот их русский перевод оставляет желать лучшего).